# XPath text() expression that contains a new line

Tags: xpath

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<a href="/site/somesite/">
                          somesite</a>
```

My question is how can I write an XPath expression that must use the `text()` property to match the `somesite` link and I cannot change the source?

Comment: Please clarify (1) exactly what you want to extract, and (2) how you can uniquely identify it within the entire document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to lookup the URL based on the link text, or the link text based on the URL. This will get you the URL:

```
//a[normalize-space() = 'somesite']/@href
```

This will get you the text:

```
normalize-space(//a[@href = '/site/somesite/'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `normalize-space()`, which will throw away the leading and trailing whitespace characters(and condense repeating spaces in the middle of the text into a single space), so that you can compare the normalized `text()` and use to filter in a predicate.

```
a[normalize-space(text())='somesite']
```